# Pandas have row value based on condition that is related to previous row's value

Tags: python, pandas, row, shift

I have 13 columns of values in a pandas dataframe, and around 8000 rows. This is called Position.

I need to create a new data frame based on this, but where the value of each row only changes if the difference between it and the previous row is >1, otherwise it is the same value as the previous row. I cannot figure out how to do it. As an example, take the data frame below.

Position: (this is the original data)

```
A B
0 1
1 9
3 8
2 7
1 9
5 8
6 9
```

Position Final: (this is what I need to change it to)

```
A B
0 0
0 9
3 9
3 7
1 9
5 9
5 9
```

If I was doing it in excel, it is a relatively simple formula. Assuming original valued in column A, and output in column C, then column C's formula would be: `C2 = IF(abs(A2-C1)>1,A2,C1`, and filled down, with C1 being 0 or hardcoded.

The current code I have is:

```
Positionfinal = Position  
(np.abs(Position - Positionfinal.shift(periods=-1))>=1)* Positionfinal.append(Position) +  (np.abs(Position - Positionfinal.shift(periods=-1))<1)*Positionfinal.append(Positionfinal.shift(periods=-1))
```

But the results I get are wrong completely.

Comment: *IF(abs(A2-C2)>1*, what value c2 has? won't it create a cyclic reference in excel?

Comment: Sorry, that should be C1, will edit it now

Comment: why are the value in B changing? also, do you need A to be updated or to introduce column C.

Answer (score 0):

To update the values, it will be necessary to iterate over the rows.
Shifting the dataframe will not be enough because the process described requires an iterative procedure. For instance, in rows 2,3,4 the A column had values `3 2 1` and the updated is `3 3 1`, but shifting the dataframe the original values would be kept because the maximum difference between consecutive values is 1 in this case.

The solution below uses pandas `df.iterrows` function to update all the columns simultaneously. The resulting values are then transformed into an updated dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create input data from OP's example
in_data =  np.array([
    [0,1],
    [1,9],
    [3,8],
    [2,7],
    [1,9],
    [5,8],
    [6,9]
    ])

# transform into a dataframe
Position = pd.DataFrame(in_data, columns=list('AB'))

# Create a variable to store the expected output
test = np.array([
    [0,0],
    [0,9],
    [3,9],
    [3,7],
    [1,9],
    [5,9],
    [5,9]
    ])

# Initialize auxiliary variables
updated_value = 0*Position.iloc[0].values # equivalent to [0,0], with same shape as Position rows
values = []

for idx, row in Position.iterrows():
    # np.where implements the required condition and updates the values
    # if condition is true, the previously registered value is kept
    # if condition is false, we update with the value of current row
    updated_value = np.where(np.abs(updated_value - row.values) <= 1, updated_value, row.values)
    values.append(updated_value)

# transform into a dataframe
PositionFinal = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=list('AB'))

# Compare with expected output
np.alltrue(PositionFinal == rest_test) # output: True
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I do the above I get: "ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (8756, 13)"

Comment: see updated code. But note that without data structure that is similar to what you're trying to do, it is harder to solve the problem.

Comment: so maybe I have explained things incorrectly. Let's ignore column C completely for now. Let's only look at column A with the numbers you provided above.

updatedA should be: 3, 0 , 3, 3, 0. (So updatedA is just column A, with the value in each successive row being kept the same as long as the difference between it and the new value is <=1. So in row 0, it is 3 for both. In row 2, that is a difference of 3, so updatedA updates to the new value (0). Row 3, same as previously, and updates to value 3. Row 3, the difference is only 1, so it does not update and the value remains 3 etc

Comment: Hi @nk123, I hadn't understood the problem previously. Thank you for providing further clarifications. I think that the updated solution is now correct. I used the data you provided to test it with success, but you can comment here if there are further necessary modifications.